# Going from URL encoded accented e to accented e in a .json text file using Python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, url-encoding

I am copying strings containing the word `cafe` (but with an accented `e`) from a javascript source file into a python script where I need to do some processing over the data and then output some JSON.  I am having some trouble getting my head around the encoding/decoding details though.  This is perhaps best illustrated with an example:

```
$ python
>>> import urllib2, json
>>> the_name = "Tasty Caf%C3%E9"
>>> the_name
'Tasty Caf%C3%E9'
>>> the_name_unquoted = urllib2.unquote(the_name)
>>> the_name_unquoted
'Tasty Caf\xc3\xe9'
>>> json.dumps({'bla': the_name_unquoted})
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
```

I've spent some time trying to understand how encodings work, though clearly I'm not getting it.  Exactly what encoding/format (any other appropriate terminology here?) is `the_name_unquoted` in above and what is it about it that utf8 cannot decode correctly?

Answer (score 1):

That because that character is supported by unicode encoding. You can fix this by converting the string to unicode.

```
the_name = u'Tasty Caf%C3%E9'
```

Alternatively, if a string exists already, you can convert it.

```
the_name = 'Tasty Caf%C3%E9'
the_name = unicode(the_name) 
# or..
the_name = the_name.decode('utf8', the_name)
```

Comment: `>>> the_name = 'Tasty Caf%C3%E9' >>> the_name = unicode(the_name) >>> print urllib2.unquote(the_name)` gives `Tasty CafAe` with a horizontal line above the A and an accent above the e.  Any idea why I'm getting the `A` in Cafe?